How to read git svn internal config values
I want to read the svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev config value.
Noticed that it is not in the .config file, but in <project>\.git\svn\.metadata
When I execute git svn clone command, I can see it sets the value using
'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' config svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev 12094
But when I try to read it
'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' config svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev
it gives empty result (I think it only reads from .config files)
How to read from the .metadata file and get this config value.
[I am using windows + git bash]

git config -f <config-file>. git config -f .git\svn\.metadata

Below is the command
git config --file=<local_repo_dir>/.git/svn/.metadata svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev
Thanks @phd
